# Custom Role Membership Provider: how to set specific Roles to the user in order to use HttpContext.User.IsInRole method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm implementing custom Authorization with OpenId.
In the database I have User Name (unique), OpenId (unique) and set of User Roles.

While the user is being Authorized, I set

```
//GetRolesFromTheDBAndAssignThemToTheUser(); how?
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(GetUserName(OpenId), false);
```

And using custom attribute on controller:

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
           //..some code

           var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User; //I can get user 
           var roles = Roles; //I can get roles
           var isAlowed = roles.Split(',').Any(user.IsInRole); //validate if user is alowed to use the current page or do other stuff
        }
```

But how I can set specific Roles to the user in order to use HttpContext.User.IsInRole method?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles) object and assign this to the HttpContext.User in the Application_AuthenticateRequest function in the global.asax. I have described this in my [blog post](http://wimpool.nl/blog/DotNet/making-httpContext.current.user-your-domain-user). You can use an other IIdentity object.

Comment: So Application_AuthenticateRequest is being executed on every Authorization request.In your code you have userRepository.GetUserByEmail(Name), where do you store users?

Comment: Application_AuthenticateRequest is executed one time per request after the formsauthenticationmodule has Authenticaticated the request. My users are stored in a sql-server database with EF.

Comment: So do you select users/roles from DB every request? My idea was to select user+roles only ones, while Log on. For now I use session to store (cache) user's roles, but in the case of a web farm it will not work.. So I thought, I can store roles in the cookie, using formsauthenticationmodule encryption.

Comment: Yes I select the user and roles from the database at every request. It is a simple query with minimal impact on website performance for my website.